# How to create static pages using templates in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create static pages in wordpress. Is it possible?
My website structure like this

```
Home
About
   Mission
   Leadership
   Blog
   Contact Us
Support
```

Home page i have created using fron-page.php. But i don't know how to create static pages. Templates is helpful to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when someone clicks on a page, it looks for page-pagename.php. So creating a page called page-blog.php, page-mission.php, page-leadership.php should open the relavant page and inside it you can do what ever you want. Another way is to use templates, create a php file in your theme and add the below comments in the begining.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: My Custom Page
 * Description: A Page Template with a darker design.
 */
```

Now from the admin panel when you any page, you  will see a new option to select the "MY CUSTOM PAGE" template.

Comment: Thank you sir.. i got a idea from you.. thanks a lot..:)